# how to create pagination function for dynamically created table

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have table of data which was fetched from API.I can able to create a table in web page and all 100 datas was displayed in one page. please some one help me create function for pagination in java script

idea for pagiante the table of data in pages. the table was created dynamically from api data

```
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rajavasanthan/jsondata/master/pagenation.json")
.then((data)=>data.json())
.then((data)=>{

  var k = '<tbody>'
    for(i = 0;i < data.length; i++){
        k+= '<tr>';
        k+=' <td>' + data[i].id + '</td>';
        k+=' <td>' + data[i].name + '</td>';
        k+= '<td>' + data[i].email + '</td>';
        k+= '</tr>';
        const my=data[i];
        
    }
    k+='</tbody>';
    document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML = k;
})
```

Comment: If you are looking for a plain JS solution, I found this in SOF. http://jsfiddle.net/Lzp0dw83/ 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this topic? Are you sure this is a CSS related problem?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. I can help you with the code but I will need more details, does the API server support pagination, if yes, how is it taking the pagination data? All you need to do in the frontend is pass that pagination data accordingly in your API call. Some APIs have a fixed page size and you can pass the page number only, others have a flexible page size and you can pass offset and limit accordingly. 
You can find numerous 3rd party packages/CDN to help you with this if you are not able to create the logic, otherwise pls provide more details and I can help you with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be the cleanest approach, but this will add a client-side pagination for a dynamic table that is getting populated dynamically.

```js
let rawData; // used to store globally the response JSON from API
const rowsPerPage = 22; // set how many rows each page will have

// Calculates the total page count based on the rows per page and total records
const calculatePageCount = (totalRecords, recordsPerPage) => {
  console.log(`Having ${rowsPerPage} records per page, you will need ${Math.ceil(totalRecords/recordsPerPage)} pages.`);
  return Math.ceil(totalRecords / recordsPerPage);
}

// Calculates the remaining records of the last page (since last page might not be fully populated by rows)
const calculateRemainder = (totalRecords, recordsPerPage) => {
  console.log(`Having ${rowsPerPage} records per page, last page will have ${totalRecords - Math.floor(totalRecords/recordsPerPage)*recordsPerPage} records.`);
  return totalRecords - Math.floor(totalRecords / recordsPerPage) * recordsPerPage;
}

// Function that replaces the HTML of table, with data specified by starting and ending indexes.
function populateTable(startIndex, endIndex) {
  let k = '<tbody>';
  for (let i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++) {
    k += '<tr>';
    k += ' <td>' + rawData[i].id + '</td>';
    k += ' <td>' + rawData[i].name + '</td>';
    k += '<td>' + rawData[i].email + '</td>';
    k += '</tr>';
  }
  k += '</tbody>';
  document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML = k;
}

fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rajavasanthan/jsondata/master/pagenation.json")
  .then((data) => data.json())
  .then((data) => {

    rawData = data;
    const pageCount = calculatePageCount(data.length, rowsPerPage);
    const remainder = calculateRemainder(data.length, rowsPerPage);

    // Initial population of table
    if (rowsPerPage > data.length) populateTable(0, data.length);
    else populateTable(0, rowsPerPage);

    // Add pagination buttons if records need more than 1 page
    if (pageCount > 1) {
      let p = '<div class="pagination">';
      for (let j = 0; j < pageCount - 1; j++) {
        p += `<button onclick="populateTable(${j*rowsPerPage},${j*rowsPerPage+rowsPerPage})">${parseInt(j + 1)}</button>`;
      }
      // Add the last page button which might have less row records
      if (remainder !== 0) {
        p += `<button onclick="populateTable(${(pageCount-1)*rowsPerPage},${(pageCount-1)*rowsPerPage+remainder})">${pageCount}</button>`;
      } else {
        p += `<button onclick="populateTable(${(pageCount-1)*rowsPerPage},${(pageCount-1)*rowsPerPage+rowsPerPage})">${pageCount}</button>`;
      }
      p += '</div>';
      document.getElementById('pagination').innerHTML = p;
    }

  })
```

```css
.console-space {
  height: 60px;
}

.pagination {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  gap: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableData"></table>
<div id="pagination"></div>

<div class="console-space"></div>
```